# PHP Classes not returning data PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to return a record from my table with the following class...

```
class User {
   public function getCredits($uid)
   {
       $rs = mysql_query("select bank from `users` where id = '$uid'");
       $row=@mysql_fetch_object($rs);
       return $row->bank;
   }
}
```

I output this data with the following...

```
    <?php print $User->getCredits(); ?>
```

Im not given anything however, as though my code cannot be read and my broweser just display a white page?

Comment: Don't put `@` in your code. It's hiding any errors that might occur. My guess is `mysql_fetch_object` is throwing an error and you're suppressing it.

Comment: and please do not use an `mysql_*` functions. Instead go with `mysqli_` or PDO!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). People who want this message: https://gist.github.com/MadaraUchiha/3881905

Comment: I never seems to amaze me how many of this questions would not have been asked if the poster actually did any kind of rudimentary debugging for themselves before asking the question here. A simple `var_dump()` of `$uid`, the actual query string, or of `$row` would have revealed this problem immediately.  The first thing you should always do when code is not behaving the way you expect it to is to debug.  You should of course also have code to handle all possible edge cases (query failure, query returning 0 rows, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

You have:

```
   $rs = mysql_query("select bank from `users` where id = '$uid'");
```

but call the method with `->getCredits()`, so `$uid` is going to be a null, and your query ends up being

```
 select bank from users where id = ''
```

Assuming the `id` field is a standard integer/auto_increment, there will be **NO** records that have a blank id, so you get back an empty set. So fetch_object will return a boolean false to indicate a fetch failure (no records to fetch), and you blindly try to use that boolean false as your data elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the function a parameter:

```
<?php print $User->getCredits(); ?>
```

Pass it the proper `$uid` for the query. Also, see @BenjaminGruenbaum comment on deprecated extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class User {
   public function getCredits($uid)
   {
       $rs = mysql_query("select bank from `users` where id = '".$uid."'");
       $row= @mysql_fetch_array($rs);
       return $row['bank'];
   }
}
```